# Dual boot separate SSD

Tags: dual-boot, server, grub2, windows-10

I've got Windows 10 on 1 SSD and Ubuntu Server on another SSD.
When I boot my machine it automatically takes me straight to the Ubuntu login screen.
I would like to see the GRUB menu with the option of running windows instead of using the BIOS to boot.
What do I need to do to get the GRUB menu to appear ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug that is still not fixed (in February 2016):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1273764

Temporary solution:

https://gist.github.com/LeahCim/9332432

Optionally I modify /etc/default/grub

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false

GRUB_TIMEOUT=5

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

## (default and savedefault should remember to boot the last booted OS)

After everything run:

sudo update-grub

to apply options,

Reboot.